# How to fix ListView Data Binding to display added items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to do `ListView` with `ItemTemplate` with `CheckBox` and `TextBlock` control and bind data to it. However, the list does not display added items.

Here is my XAML code:

```
 <ListView x:Name="WarrantyCategory_ListView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="Single" Header="Category:" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFC7C7C7" Margin="10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding WarrantyCategories}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="Description_CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionItem_TextBlock"     Text="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is my WarrantyCategory class:

```
public class WarrantyCategory
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public WarrantyCategory(bool isChecked, string category)
    {
        IsChecked = isChecked;
        Category = category;
    }
}
```

and my Page code behind:

```
public AddWarrantyDescriptionPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
    InitializeCategoryList();
}

private void InitializeCategoryList()
{
    WarrantyCategories.Add(new WarrantyCategory(false, "Computers"));
    WarrantyCategories.Add(new WarrantyCategory(false, "Mobile"));
    WarrantyCategories.Add(new WarrantyCategory(false, "Music"));
    WarrantyCategories.Add(new WarrantyCategory(false, "Video"));

}
```

Comment: check output window for binding errors, and make sure `WarrantyCategories` is `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: What's the datacontext of the page?

Comment: WarrantyCategories is ObservableCollection.
DataContext of the page - i don't see it in my code.
But don't you think that it should work?
ListView has ItemsSource as ObservableCollection and controls have binding to different properties...

Comment: Now i got it:
In MainPage code behind i should put:

this.DataContext = WarrantyCategoriesList;

and set ListViw ItemsSource like this:

ItemsSource="{Binding}"